# Does it exist: context aware, autocompleting, XML editor with API for including into my app

Tags: java, xml, autocomplete

I need an API-addressable, Java-based XML editor that is context aware.  For instance, if you give the editor a schema for the XML document that is supposed to be generated, then, as the user is editing the XML, they will have access to recommendations and autocomplete for XML elements and attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what environment this should run in...

Assuming Java, the netbeans editor is very solid and it should be possible to embed it in external Java applications.  Obviously, that would involve brining a large portion of netbean's code along with it though.

I haven't used it, but it looks like [Jaxe](http://jaxe.sourceforge.net/) might be provide a solution as well.

Comment: ... looks interesting so far.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to look at would be oXygen. The  Author component can be integrated into a web application as a Java Applet.

http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author.html

Example:

http://www.oxygenxml.com/demo/AuthorDemoApplet/author-component-dita.html